# Binary tree from unsorted array

Tags: data-structures, binary-tree, pascal

I have an array of records from which I am trying to construct a binary tree.
The end result should be as follow. -1 represents null and if both the left and right pointer are -1, it is a leaf node.

```
| Index | Left Pointer | Data | Right Pointer |
|:-----:|:------------:|:----:|:-------------:|
|   0   |       1      |  17  |       4       |
|   1   |       2      |   8  |       3       |
|   2   |      -1      |   4  |       7       |
|   3   |      -1      |  12  |       6       |
|   4   |       5      |  22  |       8       |
|   5   |      -1      |  19  |       -1      |
|   6   |      -1      |  14  |       -1      |
|   7   |      -1      |   5  |       -1      |
|   8   |       9      |  30  |       -1      |
|   9   |      -1      |  25  |       -1      |
```

This is my current code:

```
type node = record
    data : string;
    left : integer;
    right : integer;
end;

var
  binaryTree : array[0..9] of node;

procedure output;
var
    i : integer;
begin
    for i := 0 to 9 do
    begin
        writeln('Data: ' , binaryTree[i].data);
        writeln('Left: ' , binaryTree[i].left);
        writeln('Right: ' , binaryTree[i].right);
    end;
end;

procedure takeInput;
var
    i : integer;
begin
    for i := 0 to 9 do
        readln(binaryTree[i].data); 
end;

procedure initialisePointers;
var 
    i : integer;
begin
    // initialise to -1 for null
    for i := 0 to 9 do
    begin
        binaryTree[i].left := -1;
        binaryTree[i].right := -1;
    end;
end;

procedure setPointers;
var
    i : integer;
    root, currentNode : node;
begin
    // first value becomes root
    root := binaryTree[0];
    for i := 1 to 9 do
    begin
        currentNode := root;
        while true do
        begin
            if binaryTree[i].data < currentNode.data then
            begin
                if currentNode.left = -1 then
                begin
                    currentNode.left := i;
                    break;
                end
                else
                    currentNode := binaryTree[currentNode.left]
            end
            else
            begin
                if binaryTree[i].data >= currentNode.data then
                begin
                    if currentNode.right = -1 then
                    begin
                        currentNode.right := i;
                        break;
                    end
                    else
                        currentNode := binaryTree[currentNode.right]
                end;
            end;
        end;
    end;
end;

begin
    takeInput;
    initialisePointers;
    setPointers;
    output;
end.
```

With the input shown in the table, I get an output of all pointers remaining at -1 as initialised. Any idea why this may be?

Answer (score 1):

In Pascal, records are value types, so when you do e.g.

`root := binaryTree[0];`

then `root` is a *copy* of `binaryTree[0]`.

When you set fields in `root` you are setting fields in the copy.

If you want chose changes reflected back in the `binaryTree` array, you have to assign the value back after use:

`binaryTree[0] := root;`

Or else, use pointers, but I am not sure you have learned about those yet.

Comment: Thanks, I understand what the issue is now. But could you please point out where exactly I need to add this.

Comment: The simplest way to fix your current code is probably going to be eliminating the locals `root` and `currentNode` in `setPointers`. Instead, use indexes into `binaryTree`.